# Sass control directive @for with whole and decimal numbers

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to suffix whole number and decimal numbers to a CSS class selector with that very value passed on as a percent.

For example:

`.percentage-100` would have a `width` of `100%` - this works.

`.percentage-50.5` would have a width `width` of `50.5%` - this does not work.

That said, my Sass control directive is respecting whole numbers and assigning the value but not decimals.

I could use some insight from the Sass experts out there on what is currently wrong with this formula,

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .percentage-#{$i} {
        &:after {
            $value: ($i * 1%);
            width: $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The second example won't work because the dot `.percentage-50.5` chains two classes: `.percentage-50` and `.5`.

Secondly, a class cannot start with a number so `.5` is an invalid class name. More about valid class names [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors).  A dot can't be used to indicate a decimal value in any class. You should replace the second dot with an underscore or hyphen.